# authzed/spicedb - using reader connection to Postgres db based on bearer token

Tags: postgresql, amazon-aurora, spicedb

I need help with one interesting question: how to change DB connection in runtime based on bearer token in the authzed/spicedb.

For example, I`m using AWS Aurora, main Postgres DB + Postgres Reader, and for one of the services I need to use reader DB, to separate load.

If someone knows hot to do this, please help :)